# ffmpeg - Как обойти неравноверное разделение на сегменты при базовой кодировке?

Tags: ffmpeg

Пример запроса:
`ffmpeg -i 'input.mp4' -c:v libx264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)" -segment_time 20 -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment output%03d.mp4`

Если использую в запросе `-c:v libx264`, то время сплита длится довольно долго, но отрабатывает корректно.
В целом меня устраивает исходный кодек, поэтому я попробовал `-c:v copy`, то есть кодек не меняем, что делает процесс сплита практически моментальным, но возникает проблема, выходные отрезки не по 20 секунд а:
`20,5 сек`
`18,5 сек`
`21 сек`
Как с этим бороться?
Почему при модификации `-c:v copy` сплит происходит неравномерно?

Comment: Разбивать можно только по ключевым кадрам. Как ключевые кадры были расставлены в исходном кодеке, так и разбивает

Comment: @andreymal  то есть варианта быстрого сегментирования в данном случае не существует?